# Migrate Spring Cloud from OAuth 2.0 to OAuth 2.1

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway, spring-authorization-server

I have a old Spring Cloud gateway working with Keyclock server. I don't have Web UI for login because the project is a Rest API. OAuth 2.0 is used with Grant type password.

I want to migrate to OAuth 2.1 but Grant type password is deprecated.

Can you advise in my case what would be the best way to migrate the project in order again to have user name and password to issue a token in order to authenticate users and make API requests?

Looking at this guide https://connect2id.com/learn/oauth-2-1 I think JWT bearer grant type is a good candidate?

What if I create my own grant type similar to password grant type?

Comment: Just wondering why this question is tagged spring-authorization-server? It doesn't seem to be specific to Spring or SAS at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST APIs secured with OAuth2 are resource-servers. [Configure your Spring applications as such](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials).

The flow **clients** use to get access-token is not relevant for **resource-servers**. Do not create your own. Clients use:

- `authorization-code` to act **on behalf of a user** (physical person who logs in)
- `client-credentials` if it's a program you allow to issue queries **not related to a user** (batch process or any other trusted service)

Configuring a resource-server for Keycloak with the spring-boot starter libs linked above can be as simple as:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@EnableMethodSecurity
public static class WebSecurityConfig { }
```

```
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].location=https://localhost:8443/realms/master
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].authorities.claims=realm_access.roles,ressource_access.some-client.roles

com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.cors[0].path=/some-api
```

Configuring another OIDC authorization-server than Keycloak is just  a mater of editing issuer location and authorities claims.

You might also use `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` directly as described [in first tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken). Spring-addons starters are just thin wrappers around it which save quite some java conf. Here is what you have to write to achieve the same as above:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    interface Jwt2AuthoritiesConverter extends Converter<Jwt, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Bean
    Jwt2AuthoritiesConverter authoritiesConverter() {
        // This is a converter for roles as embedded in the JWT by a Keycloak server
        // Roles are taken from both realm_access.roles & resource_access.{client}.roles
        return jwt -> {
            final var realmAccess = (Map<String, Object>) jwt.getClaims().getOrDefault("realm_access", Map.of());
            final var realmRoles = (Collection<String>) realmAccess.getOrDefault("roles", List.of());

            final var resourceAccess = (Map<String, Object>) jwt.getClaims().getOrDefault("resource_access", Map.of());
            // We assume here you have "spring-addons-confidential" and
            // "spring-addons-public" clients configured with "client roles" mapper in
            // Keycloak
            final var confidentialClientAccess = (Map<String, Object>) resourceAccess
                    .getOrDefault("spring-addons-confidential", Map.of());
            final var confidentialClientRoles = (Collection<String>) confidentialClientAccess.getOrDefault("roles",
                    List.of());
            final var publicClientAccess = (Map<String, Object>) resourceAccess.getOrDefault("spring-addons-public",
                    Map.of());
            final var publicClientRoles = (Collection<String>) publicClientAccess.getOrDefault("roles", List.of());

            return Stream
                    .concat(realmRoles.stream(),
                            Stream.concat(confidentialClientRoles.stream(), publicClientRoles.stream()))
                    .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).toList();
        };
    }

    interface Jwt2AuthenticationConverter extends Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {
    }

    @Bean
    Jwt2AuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter(
            Converter<Jwt, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> authoritiesConverter) {
        return jwt -> new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authoritiesConverter.convert(jwt));
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(
            HttpSecurity http,
            Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> authenticationConverter,
            ServerProperties serverProperties)
            throws Exception {

        // Enable OAuth2 with custom authorities mapping
        http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter);

        // Enable anonymous
        http.anonymous();

        // Enable and configure CORS
        http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());

        // State-less session (state in access-token only)
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Disable CSRF because of state-less session-management
        http.csrf().disable();

        // Return 401 (unauthorized) instead of 403 (redirect to login) when
        // authorization is missing or invalid
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
            response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "Basic realm=\"Restricted Content\"");
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
        });

        // If SSL enabled, disable http (https only)
        if (serverProperties.getSsl() != null && serverProperties.getSsl().isEnabled()) {
            http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
        } else {
            http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresInsecure();
        }

        // Route security: authenticated to all routes but actuator and Swagger-UI
        // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/actuator/health/readiness", "/actuator/health/liveness", "/v3/api-docs", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
        // @formatter:on

        return http.build();
    }

    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        // Very permissive CORS config...
        final var configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));

        // Limited to API routes (neither actuator nor Swagger-UI)
        final var source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/greet/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me some extended example how to use `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` with `client-credentials`, please?

Comment: Read my answer again: the **resource-server** does not care about the flow the **client** used to get an access-token. The request being authorized with a Bearer access-token is all that matters for the resource-server. Refer to the doc of your **authorization-server** to know to declare a client with client-credentials. Follow the link in my answer for a sample with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`.

Comment: I have one additional question is there a suitable solution for this use case: Client is using token generated manually by some admin guy and send manually to the user. This token is used to send requests into header of the API requests using "Basic ....." and the token is used without default expiration. If possible the token is authenticated every time with authorization server.

Comment: This depends on your authorization-server. Refer to its doc. To my knowledge, Keycloak does not allow that, and considering how easy it is to configure a client with client-credentials to automatically fetch an access-token from the authorization server, I can't see a valid use-case.

Answer (score 0):

A summary of the relevant grant types might be:

- [Resource Owner Password](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3): Used by a client to collect the user's password, and exchange it at the authorization server for an access token. There aren't many good use cases for this grant type considering the [security issues](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-19#section-2.4), and should be replaced with Authorization Code. Deprecated in OAuth 2.1.
- [Authorization Code](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-05#section-4.1): Used by a client to initiate a browser-based flow involving an end user to obtain an access token with scopes granted by the authorization server and consented to by the user. Preferred any time there's a user involved. Input-constrained environments (e.g. device with no keyboard) can alternatively use the [Device Authorization Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8628).
- [Client Credentials](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-05#section-4.2): Used by a client in possession of a secret issued by an authorization server to obtain an access token on its own behalf. Useful in many service-to-service architectures with stateless APIs (resource servers).
- [JWT Bearer](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7523#section-2.1): Used by a client in possession of a JWT (assertion) issued by one authorization server to obtain (exchange it for) an access token from another authorization server or from the same authorization server but with different scopes/authorities. How the original JWT is obtained is not specified. Could be used (for example) to distribute Client Credentials for a single auth server which could issue tokens that can be used to obtain access tokens from one or many other auth servers in a distributed system.

Unless you have more specific requirements, the Client Credentials grant would seem like the best option.

Since you mentioned users are involved but you don't have a UI, I assume they are not users of a web-based client. If they are, the client (such as a javascript/SPA app) should be using authorization code. Your application is not the client if it accepts access tokens, it is the resource server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I too think that `Client credentials` are for now candidate solution. I have one additional question is there a suitable solution for this use case: Client is using token generated manually by some admin guy and send manually to the user. This token is used to send requests into header of the API requests using "Basic ....." and the token is used without default expiration. If possible the token is authenticated every time with authorization server.

Comment: It's hard to tell from your description whether you're describing an "API key" or something else. If it uses "Basic" it's just HTTP basic, which means the username/password are encoded into the token. It wouldn't be secure if you wanted to keep the password a secret from the user. You can always have an operator/admin use their own Client Credentials to generate a token, but it's not generally recommended that they would share that with someone else. I think each client should have their own secret.